# exit fullscreen OMX Player

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4, omxplayer

I started a omx instance based on this script. it works great, but I can't quit the player with q or alt f4 or ctrl-z.in desktop the keyboard commands always arrive on the desktop. especially if I start the script on the raspberry in CLI mode, I would never get out of the video.

What can I do here?

```
#!/bin/bash
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: omxplayer
# Required-Start:
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: Displays video file in a loop using omxplayer
# Description:
### END INIT INFO

# Video (replace with the path and file name of your video)
video_path=/home/pi/video.mp4

#---- There should be no need to edit anything below this line ----

# Start displaying the video loop
case "$1" in start)
screen -dmS videoloop sh -c "omxplayer -o both $video_path -b --loop --no-osd"
echo "Video Playback Started"
;;

# Stop displaying video loop
stop)
sudo killall omxplayer.bin
echo "Video Playback Stopped"
;;

# Restart video loop if it died
repair)
if !(ps -a | grep omx -q)
    then
    screen -dmS videoloop sh -c "omxplayer -o local $video_path -b --loop --no-osd"
    echo "The Video is now running"
fi
;;

*)

echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/videoloop {start|stop|repair}"

exit 1

;;
esac
```

Comment: How about using `service stop`?

Comment: it should work with  keyboard shortcuts. I can't see the terminal window, can't switch with alt-tab to the terminal...

Comment: As `omxplayer` is not started from your user and nor is it attached to your keyboard it will never see your keystrokes.